# html prettified json ignores new line chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to prettify my json output on html page and I am doing this with the following code:

```
$.each($('td.pretty_json'), function(key, value){      
      $(this).html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse($(value).text()), null, 2) + '</pre>');   
 });
```

The problem is that in this prettified json new line chars are not recognized and I get this:
[image: img]

The string becomes too long and table cells get stretched too far off the screen. I tried to apply some custom styles like word-wrap or word-break but it did not help. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome, thak you.

Comment: json can not be interpreted as html, what you are trying to do?

Comment: It would not be valid JSON any more if you would break the string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be right to break the string literals in JSON, as it would in fact invalidate that JSON.

Instead, use another solution to your initial problem (that the table becomes too wide). One solution could be to add horizontal scrollbars to the cells that have such JSON.

Little demo:

```js
$.each($('td.pretty_json'), function(key, value){    
    $(this).html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse($(value).text()), null, 2) + '</pre>');   
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }

td.pretty_json {
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td class="pretty_json">{ "property": "this is a test\nnext line" }</td><td class="pretty_json">{ "property": "this is a test\nnext line" }</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pretty_json">{ "property": "this is a test\nnext line" }</td><td class="pretty_json">{ "property": "this is a test\nnext line" }</td></tr>
</table>
```